# how to get random only date(not with the time) within a range in mysql

Tags: mysql

How can I select a random date within a specific inclusive range, let's say '1950-01-01' and '1999-12-31' with mysql workbench? i try with this but it is not working, suggest any function method that will be more helpful. i also found that other question which also belongs to random datetime but i want to specify the random number also like some times it comes the same day and sometime it comes the next day my requirement is different as the other question specify

```
select DateAdd(DD, ROUND(DateDiff(DD, '22-09-2016', '24-10-2016') * RAND(), 0)  DD, '22-09-2016')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer takes the approach of computing the difference, in days, between your two dates and then adding a random number of days to the starting date within the range of 0 and the full difference.

```
SELECT
    DATE_ADD('1950-01-01',
             INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * DATEDIFF('1999-12-31', '1950-01-01')) DAY) AS new_date
FROM dual;
```

I didn't test your code, but one glaring error present is the way you store and write your dates:

```
22-09-2016
```

This format is not ANSI compliant, and MySQL's date functions will likely not work properly.  Instead, *always* use dates in year-month-day format, or something very similar to this.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: correct soon i get to know about it when it was not working ..thanks for the comment.

Comment: thanks for the extra information.

Answer (score 1):

You will get the random number with `DATEDIFF` and `RAND` functions, e.g.:

```
SELECT (FLOOR(RAND() * DATEDIFF('2016-10-22', '2016-09-24')));
```

Once done, you can use `DATE_ADD` to add these many days, e.g.:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2016-09-24', INTERVAL (SELECT (FLOOR(RAND() * DATEDIFF('2016-10-22', '2016-09-24')))) DAY);
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9deb/129/0)**.

Comment: You don't need a subquery in your second answer.

Comment: got it but it will take a lot time if the date difference is huge, but this is nice idea. for small date diff. thanks for comment

Comment: you have used select keyword after interval so slightly change need to be made in this query although you approach is good.